# Bringing a city in form of a graph in python

Tags: python, graph

We have New York city google map with details of work areas, residential areas, shops, travel routes. Is there any way to make graph in python from any available data set on web or using google maps ?

Or can we get some real spatial data set for cities which can be read by python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://opendata.cityofnewyork.us/data/

Publicly available datasets are available, in xlsx format, that detail current zoning, events, shops, registrations, etc. for the city in the link above.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'Path where the Excel file is stored\File name.xlsx', sheet_name='your Excel sheet name')
```

Utilize Pandas as an alternative for importing your data into Python.